# Changing the Moodle footer logo

Tags: moodle

How to change the Moodle logo which will be displayed at the footer page and change to some other logo? As per the given link [1](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/moodle-19-theme-design-customizing-header-and-footer-part-2) I have tried but I could not find the footer.html file in my themes folder.

So please help me with some other method (which does not use local machine because I'm working with a remote machine where I could access only the Moodle site, and nothing more than that) to change the logo and link of Moodle.

Comment: which version of moodle you are using? There is no `footer.html` on moodle19.

Comment: i'm using moodle version of 2.8 and theme called clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your theme - So you're not going to get a precise answer unless you post more details. But here's the gist:

Every theme is made in parts. Normally, you have a header, a content, a sidebar (or two) and a footer.

You want to be editing the footer file.

The footer file is going to be something within the lines of footer.html or footer.php... Something like that. Again, every theme is different so it could be called something completely different. Sometimes, you just need to dig around.

Please also consider that your footer file may also be contained in a sub-directory in your theme folder. So make sure you have a proper look before deciding to "call off the search".

Anyway, once you've found your footer file (Whatever it's called), you'll want to open it and find the image.

If the image is inserted as a HTML reference of location, you can find it by Ctrl+F and typing in the name of the image file. E.g. "footer.jpeg" or whatever.

If the image is inserted as a PHP relative reference, e.g. "$FooterImage" then don't change that, instead, find out where the variable is pointing to in terms of the file-path, and go and edit that image file via FTP instead. You don't **have to** keep the PHP variable, but I'd keep it in for code-integrity purposes.

Tip for the future: Please include information like name of theme and Moodle version. It enables us to help you better.

---

Clean Theme:

Things are a bit different with Clean Theme as it doesn't have a single footer file.

You need to go into **all** layout files one at a time.

Look for this div:

```
<footer id="page-footer">
...
</footer>
```

In this footer, you will find a PHP command that says:

```
echo $OUTPUT->home_link();
```

To remove the logo, remove this line.

To replace the logo, you can either:

1. Replace the "home_link" reference in PHP to point to the new image file.

Or

2. Remove the PHP line and replace it with

`?><img src="link_to_your_image" alt="Logo"><?PHP`

Remember, you will need to do this for **all** layout files.

Comment: i'm using theme called clean and moodle version is moodle 2.8

Comment: Hi Preethi, Ah. Okay. The Clean Theme is a bit funny... I'll edit my answer now to explain what you need to do. Please mark it as best answer if you find the information useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Footer replacement](https://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Footer_replacement) at the official Moodle Documentation. Hope that helps.

Comment: Please post the solution instead of a link to it. Thanks.